# can you get info about a discord.js bot on a website?

Tags: discord.js

does anyone know if its possible to send command info (statistics info) to a website so i dont have to keep on editing my website about how many guilds my bot is in

Comment: You can put your bot on a Discord bot list, then have them automatically check the amount of guilds your bot is in. If your website isn't static, you can also put the statistics on a database, and then have the website check the database every time the page is loaded.

Comment: ok thanks and i hate the main discord bot list because i got banned for making a ddos threat when i said great the discord bot website is down, i tried to appeal it so making times

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. Let's assume your website is on server A and your discord bot is on server B.

### The first option is to have B send a request to A:

B -> POST http request x amount of servers -> A validates the request and stores the payload in its database.

Here A has to listen to an endpoint for example "https://example.com/store-server-amount"

Remember to always serialize the data you receive and validate the request is from your bot and not someone else. You can send a password along with the payload in your url query

### The second option is to have A ask B for information:

A -> GET http request -> B -> Returns x amount of servers -> A -> A stores the payload in its database.